# Replace Multiple Characters in string

Tags: c#

Hi all a have a program working but return string like `")Hi("`
it should be `"(Hi)"` so i need to replace `'('` with `')'` and replace 
`')'` with `'('` 
it sounds easy

```
s.Replace('(',')').Replace(')','(')
```

the trick is that after the first replace the string change from
`")Hi("` to `"(Hi("` after the second the replace will change both characters back
the final will become `")Hi)"`
Help Please

Comment: What if you have `"(foo)Hi(bar)"`? It should become `")foo(Hi)bar("`?

Comment: no it will be (foo(Hi(bar(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Replace because it works its replacement operation on the whole string, not char by char.

A simple brute force solution could be this one

```
void Main()
{
    // A dictionary where every key points to its replacement char
    Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>()
    {
        {'(', ')'},
        {')', '('},
    };

    string source = ")Hi(";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in source)
    {
        char replacement = c;
        if(replacements.ContainsKey(c))
            replacement = replacements[c];
        sb.Append(replacement,1);

    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

You can transform this in an extension method adding to a static class

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ProgressiveReplace(this string source, Dictionary<char, char> replacements)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in source)
        {
            char replacement = c;
            if (replacements.ContainsKey(c))
                replacement = replacements[c];
            sb.Append(replacement, 1);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and call it from your code with

```
Dictionary<char, char> replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>() 
{{'(', ')'},{')', '('}};
s = s.ProgressiveReplace(replacements);
```

Comment: thank you it worked but is there a way where i do it without looping the source string i'm working with articals and books looping will be bad

Comment: Somewhere someone should loop.

Comment: sounds like it will be a pretty big string, so I would recommend `new StringBuilder(source.Length);`

Comment: Yes that could be done but at the moment I have no clue on the actual length of the string

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) replacement.

```
s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"[)](\w+)[(]", "($1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**) 
Use the following:

```
var requiredString = string.Join(string.Empty, str.Select(x=>{if (x == '(') x = ')';  else if (x == ')') x = '('; return x;}));
```

**Method 2**)
Or you can Use following Extension Method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceMultiple(this string source, Dictionary<char, char> replacements)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty , source.Select(x=>Replace(x,replacements)));
    }

    private static char Replace(char arg, Dictionary<char, char> replacements)
    {
        if(replacements.ContainsKey(arg))
            arg = replacements[arg];
        return arg;
    }
}
```

This method can be used as follows:

```
        var rep = new Dictionary<char, char> 
        { 
            { ')', '(' }, 
            { '(', ')' }, 
            // { '#', '*' }, 
            // { '*', '#' } 
        };


        var c = str.ReplaceMultiple(rep);
```

Comment: `var s = string.Concat(")Hi(".Select(c => c == '(' ? ')' : c == ')' ? '(' : c));` but it will also be slow with big strings

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = ")Hi(";            

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var c in s)
    if (c == ')')
        sb.Append('(');
    else if (c == '(')
        sb.Append(')');
    else
        sb.Append(c);

s = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy) lets you process each `Match` (needs `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`) :

```
string result = Regex.Replace(")Hi(", @"\(|\)", m => m.Value == "(" ? ")" : "(");
```

---

Alternative can be replacing one of the characters with something else:

```
string result = ")Hi(".Replace('(', '\0').Replace(')', '(').Replace('\0', ')');
```